# XML DTD Validation Error

Tags: xml, validation, dtd

**Validate Online:** http://xmlvalidator.new-studio.org

[**XML Document**](http://pastebin.com/UkEt0mT3) *(also displayed below)*

### Question 1

Why the following 6 Errors shows?

1. Line 29 Column 18 : Attribute value "1" of type ID must be a name.
2. Line 34 Column 22 : Attribute "type" must be declared for element type "dob".
3. Line 39 Column 26 : Attribute "type" must be declared for element type "address".
4. Line 49 Column 18 : Attribute value "2" of type ID must be a name.
5. Line 54 Column 22 : Attribute "type" must be declared for element type "dob".
6. Line 59 Column 27 : Attribute "type" must be declared for element type "address".

### Question 2

When I uncomment the following line no. 4

```
<!ELEMENT persona (name,dob?,address*) >
```

AND comment the following line no. 5

```
<!ELEMENT name (first_name,last_name) >
```

Why the following error shows?

- Line 4 Column 28 : An element type is required in the declaration of element type "persona".

### The XML Document with embedded DTD

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<!DOCTYPE personality [
<!ELEMENT personality (persona*) >
<!-- <!ELEMENT persona (#PCDATA|(name,dob?,address*))> -->
<!ELEMENT persona (name,dob?,address*) >
<!ELEMENT name (first_name,last_name) >
<!ELEMENT first_name (#PCDATA) >
<!ELEMENT last_name (#PCDATA) >
<!ELEMENT dob (date+,month+,year+) >
<!ELEMENT date (#PCDATA) >
<!ELEMENT month (#PCDATA) >
<!ELEMENT year (#PCDATA) >
<!ELEMENT address (building,street,city,state,country,country_code) >
<!ELEMENT building (#PCDATA) >
<!ELEMENT street (#PCDATA) >
<!ELEMENT city (#PCDATA) >
<!ELEMENT state (#PCDATA) >
<!ELEMENT country (#PCDATA) >
<!ELEMENT country_code (#PCDATA) >

<!ATTLIST persona id ID #REQUIRED >
<!ATTLIST name type (string|number) "string" >

]>

<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="xmlstyle.css" ?>

<personality>
    <persona id="1">
        <name type="string">
            <first_name>Abhisek</first_name>
            <last_name>Pattnaik</last_name>
        </name>
        <dob type="number">
            <date>29</date>
            <month>8</month>
            <year>1990</year>
        </dob>
        <address type="string">
            <building>Plot-471</building>
            <street>Sahid Nagar</street>
            <city>Bhubaneswar</city>
            <state>Odisha</state>
            <country>India</country>
            <country_code>91</country_code>
        </address>
    </persona>
    
    <persona id="2">
            <name type="string">
                <first_name>Anindita</first_name>
                <last_name>Patnaik</last_name>
            </name>
        <dob type="number">
            <date>5</date>
            <month>12</month>
            <year>1996</year>
        </dob>
            <address type="string">
            <building>Plot-471</building>
            <street>Sahid Nagar</street>
            <city>Bhubaneswar</city>
            <state>Odisha</state>
            <country>India</country>
            <country_code>91</country_code>
        </address>
    </persona>
</personality>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25256989/attribute-value-001-of-type-id-must-be-an-ncname-when-namespaces-are-enabled?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Line 29 Column 18 : Attribute value "1" of type ID must be a name.
Line 49 Column 18 : Attribute value "2" of type ID must be a name.
```

The value of an attribute of type ID cannot start with a digit. It must match the `Name` production in the XML specification, which rules out initial digits.

- http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-attribute-types
- http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-common-syn

---

```
Line 34 Column 22 : Attribute "type" must be declared for element type "dob".
Line 39 Column 26 : Attribute "type" must be declared for element type "address".
```

You haven't declared a `type` attribute for the `dob` and `address` elements.

---

```
<!ELEMENT persona (#PCDATA|(name,dob?,address*))>
```

This (commented out in your DTD above) is an illegal declaration. The following would be OK (but may not be what you want):

```
<!ELEMENT persona (#PCDATA|name|dob|address)*>
```

For information on the constraints regarding "mixed content", see

- http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-mixed-content
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCDATA.