# Why XML attributes that are ID must start with a letter?

Tags: xml, dtd

Firstly, I'd like to have a confirm of that, (XML attributes that are ID must start with a letter).
Because I tried to put a date (dd/mm/yyyy) as a ID, but it gives me an error if I don't add a letter at the start.
After, is there a way to identify the "date" in the DTD better than "CDATA"?

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE TVchannel SYSTEM "TVchannel.dtd">
<TVchannel>
    <dailyProgrammation date="28/11/2003">
        <programs>
            ...
        </programs>
    </dailyProgrammation>
</TVchannel>
```

DTD:

```
<!ELEMENT TVchannel(dailyProgrammation)>
<!ELEMENT dailyProgrammation(programs?)>
<!ATTLIST dailyProgrammation data CDATA #REQUIRED>
...
```

(Edit) I found useful answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25256989/attribute-value-001-of-type-id-must-be-an-ncname-when-namespaces-are-enabled) that explained me many things, however by adding **NCName** in the .dtd **VS Code** doesn't recognize it, and in the .xml it says: 'there is [1] error in the .dtd'.

`<!ATTLIST dailyProgrammation data ID NCName #REQUIRED>`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, ID values in XML follow the same rules as element and attribute names, so they have to start with a letter (and can't contain characters such as "/"). The rule makes little sense in a pure XML context, but it was inherited from SGML, where it allowed IDs to be written in contexts other than as attribute values.